# How to restore a damaged touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

Can anyone help me restoring my touchpad in my Asus Laptop: my pointer jumps all the time.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: If its hardware you need to have it repaired or replaced (could be done by the supplier or manufacturer under warranty) - nothing really can be done at the software level apart from turning it off and using a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

If its hardware you need to have it repaired or replaced (could be done by the supplier or manufacturer under warranty) - nothing really can be done at the software level apart from turning it off and using a mouse.

Note your computer, particularly if you have bought it in the last 12 months, may have some form of [notebook warranty](http://www.service.asus.com/?_escaped_fragment_=notebook-warranty/c23xh#!notebook-warranty/c23xh).

Comment: Going over my old "schmucks" answers, so you finally got your upvote!  :D